# Kotlin - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: kotlin, android-asynctask, gson

Not sure what is causing this, but i am trying request data from the api and i am getting an IllegalArgumentException

```
package com.example.tmdb

import com.google.gson.Gson
import org.jetbrains.anko.doAsync
import org.jetbrains.anko.uiThread

class MainPresenter(private val view:MainView, private val apiRepository: ApiRepository, private val gson: Gson){
    fun getMovieList(){
        doAsync {
            val data = gson.fromJson(apiRepository.doRequest(TMDBApi.getMovie()),
                MovieResponse::class.java)

            uiThread {
                view.showMovieList(data.result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Line in which i am getting exception is

```
view.showMovieList(data.result)
```

and

```
class MainPresenter(private val view:MainView, private val apiRepository: ApiRepository, private val gson: Gson){
```

Error message showing in Logcat is:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter data
        at com.example.tmdb.MainActivity.showMovieList(MainActivity.kt)
        at com.example.tmdb.MainPresenter$getMovieList$1$1.invoke(MainPresenter.kt:14)
        at com.example.tmdb.MainPresenter$getMovieList$1$1.invoke(MainPresenter.kt:7)
        at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$uiThread$1.run(Async.kt:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Parameter specified as non-null is null`. What this means is that `data.result` is coming back as null. There could be multiple reasons for that, the most common one I can think of is that the json that is returned from the api call isn't the same object as what you said in `MovieResponse::class.java`.

Regardless, the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null` comes up when you tell the compiler that the param passed into this function will never be null but is in fact `null`

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a bit of guessing here, but I assume that the following are true:

- `MovieResponse` is defined in Java
- `showMovieList()` is defined in Kotlin and accepts only non-null values

Values coming from Java are treated specially in Kotlin: you're allowed to work with them as though they are non-null, but `null` values are allowed. This is a language feature that is meant to make your life better, as the alternative is to treat *every* value that comes from Java as nullable.

You can read more about this here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types

What this means for you is that you don't get compile-time null safety, and have to solve the problem yourself. Clearly `data.result` is null sometimes, so you need to make sure to handle this scenario.

Replace these lines:

> ```
> uiThread {
>     view.showMovieList(data.result)
> }
> ```

with these:

```
data.result?.let {
    uiThread {
        view.showMovieList(it)
    }
}
```